# occupation of area or space

Tags: sentence-construction, expressions

I'm writing an article and I have used the following sentence,

`The switched-capacitor technology is used to replace the large resistors which can't be used in ICs because of their large occupation of area.`

However, I feel that `large occupation of area` is wrong, because I googled it and their was nothing similar.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Comment: Space requirements | large footprint.

Comment: You can also use "large form factor".

Comment: I would use *form factor* if I expected readers to be engineers/technically-knowlegeable and if I wanted to write at a "higher" level of sophistication. *Footprint* would probably be easier for more people to comprehend. I guess, but don't know, that engineers might not always think of things on the surface of ICs as *standing* on them, so at a very specialized level, might prefer *form factor*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your sole concern is the cumbersome phrase "large occupation of area," I think TRomano's suggestion of "large space requirements" is good.

I would consider tightening up the whole sentence though.  Perhaps:

*The smaller switched-capacitor technology replaces the large resistors, whose space requirements prevent their use in ICs.*